# Connect with two wifi adapters to networks where in each is a device with same IP

Tags: wifi, ethernet, iptables

I want to connect to my two Huawei inverters.
Each has a wifi that I can connect to and I have the built-in wifi and an additional USB wifi.
If I connect to each individually the inverter is 192.168.200.1 and the raspberry is assigned 192.168.200.2 by the DHCP in the inverter.
This can unfortunately not be changed.
The raspberry is also connected with eth to my 192.168.0.x local net.

I want to use the raspberry just to connect to both wifis at the same time and be able to reach both inverters at the same time with a unique IP from a different computer in my local net. So maybe from computer 192.168.0.190 that is not the raspberry I can reach the first inverter with 192.168.0.210 and with 192.168.0.220 the second.
ModbusTCP is what I want to do with that.

I have read lots of things and developed quite a few question marks over my head.

Any tips where to start?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why is it that in linux everything is always complicated? In windows I can do this in the GUI, here I am searching for days and find nothing and if I find anything it simply does not work, like creating two wpa_supplicant files. Yes, I have created them, and nothing happens...
Is there a hardware device like a router or something with which I can do this? I am totally willing to throw money at it.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to put them all on the same network.

- You may not be able to change what the Inverter DHCP assigns, but you should be able to turn off the DHCP. I always do this with anything that has DHCP enabled by default, including Mitsubishi heat pumps.
- Turn on the DHCP on your desktop or better still, on your router
- Liven up one inverter, find it on the router and assign it a static IP.
- Repower the inverter
- Repeat for the second inverter.
- Connect the rest of your local devices.

It is possible that you are talking about the hotspot on the inverter.  The purpose of this is to configure the inverter, not to use it on this network.  So, search for the configuration settings and setup the details of your local network on it.

Comment: You are right, it is the hotspot. But unfortunately running Modbus TCP over this wifi is much much better and more reliable than running it through the dedicated dongle.
I can not turn off DHCP on this hotspot wifi and can not assign an IP to the inverter.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the problem is that you want to use TCP to communicate with 2 devices that have the same IP address.

The only way to differentiate between the devices is the MAC address, so first you need to establish what these are, for example by connecting each device individually, and using the arp command.

Now you can connect both devices and use iptables to do mac address filtering on one of them, e.g.
`iptables -A INPUT -m mac --mac-source <mac_addr> -j DROP`

Admittedly, the switchover (disabling one, re-enabling the other) will be quite clunky, and you need to be sure that the TCP connection is closed before switching, otherwise TCP will get very confused. You'll be violating one of the primary principles, namely that every IP address on a subnet is unique.